# Translate .xml in magento

Tags: xml, magento, csv, translate

I have this:

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <redsys>
            <active>1</active>
            <model>redsys/payredsys</model>
            <order_status>processing</order_status>
            <title>Pago con tarjeta - Redsys</title>
        </redsys>
     </payment>
</default>
```

And I would like to translate "title" tag. I have .csv files with translations but I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use this, I have added translate="title" to it

```
<default>
<payment>
    <redsys translate="title">
        <active>1</active>
        <model>redsys/payredsys</model>
        <order_status>processing</order_status>
        <title>Pago con tarjeta - Redsys</title>
    </redsys>
 </payment>
 </default>
```

then add

Then add to your theme theme:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv

"Pago con tarjeta - Redsys","which_language_you_want"
```

use this in your template where you want to translate directly

```
echo Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('Pago con tarjeta - Redsys'])
```

Comment: "your_helper" is the name of csv, no? For example, if I put my translate in Mage_Paygate.csv in "your_helper" I put "Paygate".

Comment: check your config.xml in your module app/code/codepole/namespace/module_name/etc  where you have define helper

Comment: did you try without this line echo Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('Pago con tarjeta - Redsys'])

Comment: please try ones without this only add translate="title"

Comment: Only add transalte="title" and the translation of "Pago con tarjeta - Redsys" in one csv? Sorry, I am noob in magento

Comment: yes  transalte="title" in your xml and try if not work then go ahead

Comment: And in what csv I need to put my translation?  I put in Mage_Paygate.csv. It is okey?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105809/discussion-between-shakir-khan-and-oihi08).